# Standard deviation of the sum of two normally distributed random variables with a weight

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm trying to find the standard deviation of the following distribution:
$Z = kX + vY$ where $k$ and $v$ are scalar values, therefore it isn't a normal sum but it is the sum of two weighted normally distributions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't matter what distributions $X$ and $Y$ have: the SD is the square root of the variance, so you only need to compute the variance.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=linear+combination+variance for many answers.

Comment: @whuber, would my resulting variance equal to $σ^2 (z) = k*σ^2 (x) + v*σ^2 (y)$ then?

Comment: No, that can't be right, because when both $k$ and $v$ are negative you would get a negative value, which is impossible.  Plug your values into the formula given in the answer to the first duplicate at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/191588/919.